# Installing R package from BayesTree_0.3-1.tar on Windows

Tags: r

I have installed `R` and `Rtools`, and set the path to both, but when I use 
`R CMD INSTALL C:\transfer\BayesTree_0.3-1.tar` 
to install this package, I get

```
Warning: invalid package 'c:\transfer\BayesTree_0.3-1.tar'
Error: ERROR: No packages specified
```

Do I need to rebuild this as a .tar.gz, or is there another problem?
Many thanks.

Comment: From where that package comes? It is supposed to be a [tar.gz file](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/BayesTree/), not a tar file.

Comment: From the cran archive. I unpacked it and crated a tar.gz, and tried again - this time got  ERROR: compilation failed for package 'BayesTree'.  How can I find what is causing this error?

Comment: Why do you unpack it? Directly use the tar.gz you downloaded.

Comment: I downloaded BayesTree_0.3-1.tar, not tar.gz, as I said above.  That would not install, said invalid package.  I unpacked it and created a tar.gz, and got compilation failed.  What would cause compilation to fail like that? how can I resolve it?

Comment: OK. File got messed up on the download - started again at the beginning and it seems to have worked ok. thanks Pascal.